# FileWatcher in Windows Service suddenly stops working

Tags: c#, service, filesystemwatcher

I'm running a windows service in Windows 2003.  I've been adding/changing code to it every day for the last month, and everyday for the last month my filewatcher has been working.  However, it stopped working today for some odd reason.  If I revert back to old code, it still won't raise events.  I've tested the same code on my Win7 machine and it is working fine.  I'm assuming there is an external process interfering but I'm not even sure what to look for.

Here is the relevant code:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.processfileWatcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize) (this.processfileWatcher)).BeginInit();
        this.processfileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        this.processfileWatcher.Filter = "done.txt";
        this.processfileWatcher.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.processfileWatcher_Changed);
        this.ServiceName = "Service1";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.processfileWatcher)).EndInit();

    }

private void processfileWatcher_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            processfileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            //Do stuff here
            Debug.WriteLine(" End of processfileWatcher for: " + e.FullPath);
        }

        finally
        {
            processfileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

    }
```

Through debug statements I can confirm that I am reaching the end of my onStart() method.

Comment: Where are you setting the Path property of your FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: In the constructor for the Class with the /onstart/onstop methods: public Ex()
        {
            Settings = new Settings();
            InitializeComponent();
            processfileWatcher.Path = Settings.ProcessFolder;
        }

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working for you, but here are a couple generic code suggestions: 1) You don't need to cast your `FileSystemWatcher` to a `FileSystemWatcher` 2) it might be a good idea to set the Path field inside your Init code.

Comment: Put a Debugger.Launch in your OnStart then you can attach the debugger and walk through the code.  You might see some line not gettning hit or an exception that is getting swallowed.

Comment: Debugger.Launch is crashing my service... am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something is causing a lot of rapid disk changes you may be running out of buffer before you have the chance to catch the thing you are looking for, or your service's credentials may not be working for what you are monitoring.

Try granting explicit permissions then look for the buffer issue by adding a handler for the fileystemwatcher's error event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.error%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks I will try that.  Disk cleaner was running and attempting to compress old files since I only had about 35MB of space left, but I did shut the process down as I suspected it might be causing something.  I will try your suggestion first thing tomorrow morning when I get to the office and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: out of curiosity, what did you end up finding?

Comment: I have found that it had been working all along but it wasn't outputting debug statements so I had thought it wasn't being triggered.  I opened a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing it with this.processfileWatcher.Created event and see if it still raises when new files are created.
Also try setting the NotifyFilter property manually ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx)) and see if that works.

Comment: I've changed it to Created as well as choosing different directories but I am not triggering any events

Comment: Are you watching the same directory or changed it to watch a network drive or something? One more thing, you could use a debugger to debug your windows service program using debug attach to progam. see link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx]

Comment: I'm attempting to attach a debugger but it won't let me because I'm using mixed unmanaged/managed code.  I'm trying to set the debugging to managed but I don't see any debug option under configuration properties in the property pages window.

I've found that the filewatcher is now being triggered properly but instead of running through its normal code, it launches an .exe file called earlier in the code.  I'm not sure why this is happening.  I even have debug statements at the beginning of filewatcher but nothing is showing up on debugview.  The Exe has no filewatcher method.

Comment: Actually let me correct that.  I've done some more tests and the program is functioning as normal it appears, but for some reason after I launch filewatcher my debug statements (System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine) won't appear in debugview, with the exception of those from the exe.  Has anyone else come across this?